# Noun or phrase similar to clone with positive connotation?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm searching for a noun (a single word if possible) or phrase that conveys that one thing functions the same as another externally, even though the internals may differ.

Nouns such as copy, a clone, duplicate, or substitute capture only part of my meaning. Additionally, these words often have a negative connotation; they imply that the thing is derived and possibly inferior. But I don't want to imply that the other thing is derived or merely copied.

What might be some good words or phrases that give a positive connotation, perhaps giving a sense of rethinking, "re-invention", or possibly renewal? I don't need the word to necessarily signify that the new thing is alive, but I want to avoid implying that it is 'lesser'.

Here is an example sentence:

> LEG, a recent upstart in the electronics industry, has released the Tintium line of microprocessors, a [?] of Intel's Pentium line of processors. It behaves identically, but since it uses tin-arsenide for its substrate, the chips offer better reliability, especially for interstellar applications. The chip design is open source; several industry experts claim its internals are simpler and more efficient than the Pentium.

And another:

> After losing his biological leg, Alan sought the services of Biocraft LLC, who custom designed and attached a [?] of his original limb. The company says it will outlast the natural leg.

Comment: Something like an *enhancement*.

Answer (score 5):

The word you're looking for is emulate.

> emulate.
>   ˈɛmjʊleɪt/
>   verb. 
>    1. match or surpass (a person or achievement), typically by imitation.
>   "*most rulers wished to emulate Alexander the Great*"
>   "*hers is not a hairstyle I wish to emulate*"
>   COMPUTING
>    2. reproduce the function or action of (a different computer, software system, etc.).
>   "*the adaptor is factory set to emulate a Hercules graphics board*"

Adapted from Google's [definition](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%3Aemulate&oq=define%3Aemulate&a#q=define:emulate&spell=1)

If what you want it as a noun,  then I'd go with: *emulation* or even, *emulator*

It certainly connotes a desire to be similar in a positive sense,  out of awe or respect.

Comment: The noun "emulation" is usually used to describe the actions of someone - not an object. (I did that Ngram thingy to check)

Comment: @Oldbag try *emulator*

Comment: In software, the result of an emulation is often slower or otherwise inferior to the original, so this is not free from negative connotations. (In software, I would consider a clone to possibly work better than an emulation.)

Comment: @Pureferret - Yeah, that's better... But, it still gives me the sense that the latter is "trying to keep up" with the original, whereas, "analogue" (which I up-voted) or "alternative" (which I suggested) implies "another of the same kind of thing".

Comment: @skymninge I don't see that [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emulator), in my experience emulators often run on better hardware giving an overal increase in performance

Answer (score 5):

The word [**analogue**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/analogue) lacks a negative connotation and appears to convey your intended meaning well.

In your example sentences:

"...released the Tintium line of microprocessors, an **analogue** of Intel's Pentium line."

"...sought the services of Biocraft LLC, who custom designed and attached a prosthetic **analogue** of his original limb."

Comment: An analogue digital device is oxymoronic.

Comment: Because of the word's other technology-related meaning? When used in that sense, the American spelling of analog is [preferred](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/analog?s=t). I do see your point though. It could be a source of confusion if a reader is unfamiliar with the multiple meanings of the word.

Answer (score 3):

Consider a ***drop-in replacement***.

Answer (score 3):

I find it difficult to suggest a word that fits both contexts exactly the same. You may have to tailor it to your specific context.

For the leg, **replica** comes to mind: as a faithful reproduction it may look the same, but the construction can be different.

For the microprocessor, maybe "an **improvement on** Intel's Pentium line..." This suggests it had a similar ancestry, but changes course and surpasses the older model.

If this were a person you were talking about, I'd suggest a **double** or **doppelgänger**. This connotes extreme outward similarity, but doesn't lessen its importance, and even calls into question the difference in motives.

Comment: Replica for the leg example, +1.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps *[simulation](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=simulation)*

> Representation of the operation or features of one process or system through the use of another: *computer simulation of an in-flight emergency*.

*American Heritage*

The term is widely used in technology for things that mimic the function of a more naturalistic object or event. The term seems to be neutral, but may take on positive or negative tones with adjectives.

For example, *[Beatlemania](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beatlemania_(musical))* was a tribute musical featuring Beatle look-alikes and songs. It billed itself as *Not The Beatles, But an Incredible Simulation*.

A related term is *[simulator](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=simulator&submit.x=0&submit.y=0)*

> One that simulates, especially an apparatus that generates test conditions approximating actual or operational conditions.

*American Heritage*

This seems to be more often applied to a test device that is not intended to take the place of an actual device or situation.

Comment: Interesting, but simulations aren't direct substitutes for the real thing, are they? (Notwithstanding [The Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Matrix).)

Answer (score 2):

"... **[the/an equal](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/equal)** of/to Pentium's ..." might work as a noun for your first example, or "..., which equals Pentium's ..." as a verb. This would avoid the negative connotation, but it might limit your freedom to discuss how much better it is.

Your second example would, in my opinion, require qualification: "... **an/the equal in many respects** of/to ..."  The "which equals in many respects" verb form would require mentioning first the artificial limb.
IMO, it's going to be hard to describe an artificial limb without some hint of negativity vis-a-vis the real thing, however.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "*a __ of...*", if you use "*an __ to...*" you could fill in the blank with ***alternative***.

Comment: an alternative may be something quite different.

Comment: "An "alternative" would be something "different" by definition. The implication is that it serves the same purpose.

Comment: With "quite" i mean completely. "An alternative to guessing is checking dictionaries". Does it serve the same purpose? In some way. Another example from TFD: "A choice or course of action that is mutually exclusive with another: The alternative to staying in that dead-end job is to quit."

Comment: I see what you're saying... Although I believe context would eliminate the possible ambiguity.

Comment: "An alternative to his original limb" sounds a bit weird. Maybe he is getting a rifle attached to his shoulder. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Something that "functions the same as another externally, even though the internals may differ" can be called a [look-alike](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/look-alike) or [act-alike](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/act-alike). The artificial leg could be called a [simulacrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulacrum) or replica of the original, though perhaps none match exactly. There is the noun [reinvention](http://www.totodefinition.com/search.php?word=reinvention).

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would consider handling these sentences:

> LEG, a recent upstart in the electronics industry, has released the Tintium line of microprocessors, {**the equivalent of / a substitute for / which emulates / which is analogous to**} Intel's Pentium line of processors.

You wrote that in your view, 'substitute' implies a copy, or an inferior or derivative version, and is an unsuitable word choice for that reason.

But as the Tintium "behaves identically" to the Pentium line of processors, to that extent the connotation "something copied" does seem applicable here, and 'substitute' is therefore a valid possibility.

> After losing his biological leg, Alan sought the services of Biocraft LLC, who custom designed and attached a **replacement for** his original limb.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest ***twin*** as the noun you're looking for - it works in both of your examples, it has no negative connotation I'm aware of, and it literally means a copy (not merely "something similar to").

I think, however, that your first example wants to imply something a bit more involved than mere similarity, as the subsequent sentences go on to describe how the LEG chip is different from the Intel one.  A writer of such a paragraph would probably use a noun like "competitor" or "challenger" to emphasize that the new chip is in the same market/class as the Pentium but has different features.

Answer (score 0):

When something is **functionally identical** to another thing, as with your processor example, we simply say it's functionally identical. If there are exceptions, as there are with the processor example, then you would state them, as you have.

If it has superficial resemblance to another thing, as with your leg example, we might say the replacement is a **simulacrum** of the original

> a slight, unreal, or superficial likeness or semblance. (Dictionary.com)

We might also refer to the replacement as a **facsimile** of the original, but, strictly speaking, that means *exact copy*. You might use that if there is no noticeable difference. This wouldn't apply to the processor, because there is a noticeable difference in how it behaves after exposure to radiation of space travel.

Answer (score 0):

**Improved copy** is a standard term for that.